# Arrange windows in 8 tiles on Win 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, window-manager, 4k-resolution

I normally arrange my windows on my FullHD monitor side-by-side:

[image: FullHD layout (2 programs side-by-side)]

To achieve that, I can simply press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> for the left window and <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> for the right one.

I then bought a new 4K (a.k.a. UltraHD) monitor - which is great. Four times the pixels - four times the possibilities!

To actually make the space as usefull as four times my FullHD monitor would be, I want to have the arrangement possibility I had on the one screen now on all four quarters of my new screen. The problem is, that <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> does not place the windows side-by-side per quarter but for the whole screen.

What it does:

[image: UltraHD layout (2 programs side-by-side)]

What I want it to do:

[image: UltraHD layout (8 programs side-by-side)]

Does anybody know a convenient way to achieve that? 3rd party program solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsofts own [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) (i.e. FancyZones) can be used to tweak the Snap behaviour and achieve exactly what was requested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is actually what I settled on some time ago :D I dont know why this community bot reacts like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [Tiling Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager)

There are number of examples on that Wikipedia page. Perhaps a better list can be found [here](https://solutions.softonic.com/what-are-the-best-window-managers-for-windows-10).

Can't recommend a specific one, as I am the developer for one of them, and, obviously, biased :-D

Comment: At the substance you are right - and I already use i3 on Linux. But this question was specifically about Windows, as can be seen in the title and the keywords. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: @Matmarbon, well, the list I mentioned should be ok. I haven't seen a good overview article yet though.

Answer (score -1):

So now that you're familiar with Snap,
let's talk about the three other ways to arrange windows in your desktop.
These options are available and come with windows.
[Right-click on task bar](https://www.windowscentral.com/4-ways-arrange-multiple-windows)